# News list not showning after update app on Google Play Store

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Firstly CRUD Operation with Firebase Realtime Database is OK and then new release on Google Play Store. Later, I change some of other functions not news list and update on Google play Store. After update app login, news list key/value (name,image,title,etc.) not showing on list, only show list count in CardView. What happened?

```
newsRVModalArrayList.clear();
query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
        newsRVModalArrayList.add(snapshot.getValue(NewsRVModal.class));
        newsRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
        newsRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        newsRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
        newsRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
});
```

So, I delete all data (news list) in Firebase and inset new one (news). It is shown in old version app id,name,image,title. It is OK. But in new version app only show list count not show id,name,image,title. How to solve this problems?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: list is working (list count,image,title,etc) for a version 1 on playstore but only working list count and not showing (image,title,etc.) for a version  2 after update on playstore.

Comment: Since you have two different code bases and two different database schemes, most likely that's the reason why you encounter that situation.

Comment: I have one code & one database Not Changes. I think PlayStore SHA1 need to add firebase?

Comment: change minifyEnabled from true to false, my problem was solved by this.